# Can't set chrome browser language by chromeoptions

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to set chrome language to other using chromeOptions，then it doesn't work. Below is my configuration:

```
desiredCapabilities: {
      browserName: ‘chrome’,
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      acceptSslCerts: true,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: [
          ‘--no-sandbox’,
          ‘start-fullscreen’,
          ‘--lang=fr’
          //‘--headless’
        ]
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/DATADEER/51da97498c03c804d75f4b3828cedb8c

```
chromeOptions: {
   prefs: {
       intl: {accept_languages:"de-DE,de"}
   },
   args: ['headless'],
},
```